# general about .split

Tags: javascript, jquery

Markup::

```
<td class="info2 gensmall">
<span class="new1">In total there is <strong>1</strong> user online :: 1 Registered, 0 Hidden and 0 Guests </span>
 <span class="new2">We have <strong>4</strong> registered users</span>
<span class="new3">The newest registered user is <strong><a href="/u5">cldtomhil</a></strong></span>
<span class="new4">Our users have posted a total of <strong>12</strong> messages</span>
</td>
```

Ok guys trying to learn the jQuery `.split`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('td .info2 .new1');
    var b = $('td .info2 .new2');
    var c = $('td .info2 .new3');
    var d = $('td .info2 .new4');
    var w = a.split("<strong>");
    var x = b.split("<strong>");
     var y = c.split("<strong>");
     var z = d.split("<strong>");
$('.new1').html('<span>"w"</span>&nbsp;Users Online');
$('.new2').html('<span>"x"</span>&nbsp;Total Users');
$('.new3').html('<span>"y"</span>&nbsp;Newest Member');
$('.new4').html('<span>"z"</span>&nbsp;Total Messages')
    });
```

Ok I know I am doing this wrong just by looking at it. Though I just can't figure out how to use the split feature, I am trying to gain the information inside the `<strong>` tags. Then once I have it I want to change the innerHTML basically with the new data like I posted with the `.html`

Yes I know it's a lot of variables but hey what can you do, I'm not a very good coder yet, and still learning some things so.

Comment: Please.. don't parse HTML like that!

Comment: There is no jQuery method of `.split()` or `$.split()`

Comment: That's not how `.split` works.

Comment: `.split()` is a native javascript String method. It works as described **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**.

Comment: ok so what exactly is split then lol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you gain the value:

```
$('td.info2 .new1 strong').text(); // returns "1"
$('td.info2 .new3 strong').text(); // returns "cldtomhil", not "<a href="/u5">cldtomhil</a>"
```

Etc. Having said that, [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a JavaScript function that splits strings given a separator. What you were trying to do was to grab the contents of an HTML element. There is no need to use string functions to do this. Use [DOM functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) (or jQuery) to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Or if you want just the text: $('td.info2 .new1 strong').text();

Comment: ok wow I forgot about .text WOW total brain fart. Thanks Salman A and Tim Banks! I'm going to go and try to render this code

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I got it to work the exact way I wanted with a little tweaking...Thank you again Salman A and Tim Banks for this nice little reminder hopefully I don't have another brain fart. :)